# How to export all tables in CSV specifying the column order

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I followed the answer indicated below to export all tables in CSV.

[How can I dump all tables to CSV for a PostgreSQL schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137140/how-can-i-dump-all-tables-to-csv-for-a-postgresql-schema)

However, I also need to specify the column order. I am thinking about running this query

```
select * from information_schema.columns order by table_name, column_name
```

and

```
select column_name1, column_name2 from table_name.
```

Is it possible to script that kind of logic with psql (Or any other program) ?

Regards

Comment: What order do you want the columns in? Alphabetic?

Comment: Yes exactly ! In alphabetical order, it would be perfect